# Excel VBA using Objects with an Index Match between worksheets Error91

Tags: vba, excel, object

I am trying to write an Excel Macro which will take the ID value assigned to a record on an unsaved spreadsheet (saving will be done as a result of passing criteria) and use this to match against a sheet which holds all of the data.  It will then have to get the status of the specific record and execute code based on that outcome.

Basically my macro splits up a spreadsheet of downloaded data and separates each sheet into a new workbook and saves it using the JobID as the name of the WS and WB.  I now require the macro to not save the Job if its status is "Completed & Retured", I can use an Index/Match on the spreadsheet to check the values are correct and working but when trying to replicate it in the Macro I am getting

> Object variable or With block variable not set (Error 91)

```
Dim ThisWbk As Workbook
Dim dbsheet As Worksheet
Set ThisWbk = ThisWorkbook
Set dbsheet = ThisWbk.Sheets("Data")
Dim objectfname As Object
Dim fname As String
Dim outcome as Object

With Application 

Set objectfname = fname    'Error occurs here

'MsgBox (objectfname)
Set outcome = .Index(dbsheet.Range(dbsheet.Cells(2, 5), dbsheet.Cells(40000, 5)), .Match(objectfname, dbsheet.Range(dbsheet.Cells(2, 1), dbsheet.Cells(40000, 1)), 0))
MsgBox (outcome)

End With
```

fname is defined earlier in the macro but it contains a 5 digit number.  I am looking for the Index/Match to use the value of fname compare it against all records in column A of dbsheet and return column E as outcome.

Any help pointing my in the correct direction would be much appreciated, currently the objectfname equals Nothing as it can't seem to get the value held in fname.

Comment: From what I can tell, Index isnt returning a specific cell range in this case. By looking at your code, you should be able to use MATCH to find the matching cell, and then build your specific cell reference from there.

On the other hand, from looking at your msgbox(outcome) it looks like you are just trying to return the value of the match, and not the range itself. In this case, use outcome as a string, remove the set in front of outcome. You will also need to add .Value after the index call. This will return a string you can interpret.

Comment: @BrandonBarney I have yet to try your first idea, I commented out `Set objectfname = fname` and tried to just use

    `outcome = .Index(dbsheet.Range(dbsheet.Cells(2, 5),     dbsheet.Cells(40000, 5).Value), .Match(fname,     dbsheet.Range(dbsheet.Cells(2, 1), dbsheet.Cells(40000, 1)), 0))`

But I am now getting Method 'Range' of object'_Worksheet' failed on that line

Comment: Do you have a command between frame and dbsheet.range? This error occurs when you reference a range that cannot be found. Also, I believe you need ".value" at the end. I don't use index often so I could be mistaken on this, but if it works like a regular range.value retern it should be needed.

Comment: `fname` is declared as a `String`, so you can't assign it to an `Object` with `Set`. That code shouldn't even compile - you should be getting a "Type mismatch". If you're intending to match `fname`, just pass it directly instead of `objectfname`.

Comment: @BrandonBarney there isn't anything in between, fname is defined earlier in the Sub there is a lot of code before these lines but they aren't relevant to this bit, I might try and take index out and use Match to get the correct row then reference from there.

Comment: @Comintern if I remove objectfname and pass fname directly I get an Object required Error